# unindent does not match any outer indentation level in my maths game

Tags: python

I'm creating a maths quiz to help get my self started with Python since I'm very new to the language and it comes up with a unindent does not match any outer indentation level error message? Could someone inform me on what this means and where my mistake lies.

Here is my code:

```
import random

questions = 0
correct = 0

print ("Welcome to the maths challenge")
print ("Out of these 10 questions how many can you get right?")

while True :
questions += 1
numberA = random.randint(0,12)
question = "What is {0}**2".format(numberA)

print(question)

response = input("Your Answer : ")

answer = numberA**2

if(int(response) == answer) :
    print("Correct!")

else :
    print("Wrong!")


 if(questions == 10) :
     print("You got {0}/{1} questions correct.").format(correct, questions)

 if correct == ("5>")
     print ("Better luck next time")

 if correct == ("5<")
     print ("You got a great score Well done!")
     break
```

Comment: The error is on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the area that is generating the error may start from:

```
 if(questions == 10) :
```

At least from what you have put in your question. With python, space and indentation dictate most of the language syntax, rather than opening and closing blocks. So it is very important that you pay attention to exactly how many spaces or tabs you use before a block, in order to keep indentation consistent.

Some IDEs will help immensely with this task, such as PyCharm. Other text editors like Notepad++ would allow you to search through your text and replace tab characters with spaces, though that may be a little bit above and beyond what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(questions == 10) :
```

and all successive lines are indented one space farther than their predecessors.  The one-space indentation doesn't match the prior block (zero spaces indented).